# Bit more info in meta faq answer - "Sorry we are no longer accepting... ", Or is it intentionally left out?

Tags: feature-request, meta, deleted-questions, post-ban, meta-faq

If it is not clear already, [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers) is the question I am talking about.

I am somewhat frequent here in meta recently, and come across many questions from users who are question banned. I think it would be helpful if we add bit more information to the answer, especially in the case when the banned user has deleted questions.

I am saying about adding 2 informations.

**1) Explain the undeletion process if OP has deleted posts.**

Currently this is what the answer tells about deleted posts.

> **Are deleted posts taken into account too?**
>
> Yes, deleted questions (if less than 30 days old when deleted) and deleted answers count
> towards an automatic ban. It's not a problem to have deleted posts.
> But if a large percentage of your posts are deleted by yourself or the
> community, then apparently they are not suitable for the site. Posting
> them consumes time from users who read them, edit them, or respond to
> them. Therefore deleted posts have an effect on the filter, among many
> other factors. Beware that an account might very well have many
> deleted posts, including auto-deleted old low-score questions, all of
> which are only visible to moderators.

Now if the banned user has deleted posts, he/she has to flag for moderator attention(with the other flag) first to undelete the question. Then only the post gets up votes and  accelerate the process of ban lifting. A sentence like,

> If you have deleted posts, flag one of them for moderator attention,
> ask them to undelete it and improve the post thereafter.

will do. Someone with better language can make it prettier. Or is it intentionally left out since moderators are busy and can't handle all undelete votes?

**2) Say that posting a question in meta won't  help.**

I am surprised it is not there already, considering the amount of questions daily getting asked in meta. Just tell in the answer itself(even make it in bold)

> *There is no point in asking for help in meta. No one there can help you to lift your ban, even if they want to. Only you can help you by
> following the process described here.*

Again anyone can suggest a better sentence.

I know it is only helpful if people read the the answer fully, but why not hope that at least 5 out of 10 people do that?

Comment: In theory this is a good idea, but people clearly aren't reading the current post....

Comment: `Say that posting a question in meta won't help.` I don't want to criticize you, but did you *read* those questions which keep creeping up here on Meta? They go like this: "I get the following message when I try to ask a question: *exact error message with link* Why?" or like this "Please lift my ban. :(" or like this: "I get this error when posting questions: *exact error message with link* What can I do to lift that ban?" ... The problem is not missing information in the post about the ban, it's ***people failing to read it at all***.

Comment: @ChrisF Agree, many of them are not.. But there are some people posting questions here on meta, since  1) they can't improve (and get up vots)their posts since they are deleted  2) as a shortcut to speedy ban lifting by asking for help in meta.

Comment: I don't think it's a bad idea to add this information. Forget about those who don't read it. Let's make the information more or less complete for those (few?) who do.

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby we can't do anything for people who are not reading it full.. We can only communicate with people who are willing to read . **We have a faq thread there since we things some people will read it.** If not, then why have that thread there?

Comment: Also, how about adding a line on the top with heading font, **Beware!!, if you don't read this full, your ban will never get lifted**

Comment: @Krishnabhadra That would be misleading since reading the post is not what will get your ban lifted. It's taking the actions explained within the post that might have the desired effect.

Comment: @Bart oops, I just added it as a joke then. But I don't think it is a bad idea to prompt people to read the answer fully, if the sentence is correct.. Infact I am going to edit the question and add it.

Comment: @Krishnabhadra Well, it already says to read "everything we're about to tell you".